# Characters that should be skipped before calling Xdocument.save

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have this problem.. I'm receiving data from a client..Using a socket connection. But this is not important. All the data is stored in an XML file using the XDocument object.
Sometimes when calling the XDocument.Save(filestream) and passing to it data with particular characters or symbols, I get an Exception like (invalid Hexadecimal character), it means that the XML file could not have some special characters ? 
If so where can I find a list of this special characters that could generate such Exceptions?

Comment: Yes `XML` is not just a text file and you can not write whatever you want whenever you want, but very often there is solution.Please provide an example of the code you write and get exception.

Comment: You would probably need to use CDATA for some parts of the document. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcdata%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Just a few more details and you would have had a definitive answer by now. Always post full error message and relevant code. But Darin has a good guess.

Comment: Thank you..I use CDATA but this not solves the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Characters in the range [0x0-0x1F] are called control characters and excluding 0x9, 0xA, 0xD they cannot be used in XML.

Here's a quote from the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets):

> [Definition: A parsed entity contains text, a sequence of characters,
>   which may represent markup or character data.] [Definition: A
>   character is an atomic unit of text as specified by ISO/IEC 10646:2000
>   [ISO/IEC 10646]. Legal characters are tab, carriage return, line feed,
>   and the legal characters of Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646. The versions of
>   these standards cited in A.1 Normative References were current at the
>   time this document was prepared. New characters may be added to these
>   standards by amendments or new editions. Consequently, XML processors
>   must accept any character in the range specified for Char. ]
>
> Character Range
>
> Char     ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] |
>   [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]  /* any Unicode character,
>   excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */

Comment: @Tigran, no, it doesn't depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Darin should get you pointed in the right direction.  I will add that if you have a tool for xml development such as [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) or [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/) you can quickly determine the offending characters.  If you don't have such a tool you can use the online xml validator from WC3 schools found here:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

This will check that the xml is well formed and if it contains invalid characters it will not be well formed.

A more unlikely scenario might be that the encoding specified by the xml document does allow the characters causing the problem. If the document is specified as UTF-8, which it probably is, then this is not likely the problem.